# Backslash appears on my string array

Tags: java

I have a `String[]` array with words inside. I would like to use the bubble sort method in order to sort them alphabetically.

Everything seems to work fine except of some words appears to be: for example, `\r\n` reduction or hierarchical `\r\n` , for that reason those words would not be placed in order.

However, when I print those words, the `"\r\n"` doesn't appear.

I tried to remove it with replace/replaceAll method but it seems it doesn't work the way it should.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reduction' and 'hierarchical'? And are you trying to add the backslashes or remove them? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'\r'` and `'\n'` symbols are not visible when you print them is because they do not produce characters - they move the cursor to a different location. One simple way of getting rid of `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and other whitespace characters on both ends of the string is calling the `trim()` method on the string. Before going into the sort, do this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != array.length ; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].trim();
}
```

After this loop, none of the words would have whitespace characters at either end, letting your sort algorithm compare the strings properly.

This assumes that no element of the `array` is `null`. If some elements can be `null`, add `null` checking to your code.

Answer (score 0):

These characters are new line characters. You should be able to call `trim()` on the string to get rid of them. Remember however that **strings are immutable in Java**.

You have to store the result of the `trim()` as the call will not modify the original string. The methods you were using should also work, but maybe you have forgotten to store the result.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the escape sequences [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Essentially, `\r` and `\n` are *escape sequences* which mean "Insert a carriage return in the text at this point" and "Insert a newline in the text at this point"

So when you go to print those words, java inserts a carriage return or newline as appropriate. I believe Windows uses `\r\n` while *nix uses `\n` to denote where a new line should be printed.

I'm not sure why `replaceAll()` didn't work; if you provided the right arguments they should work. It could be possible that you forgot to escape your backslashes.